# Kendo Panel Bar not working for alternative load of the panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-panelbar

I have a requirement where i have to show a popup on click of a button and in the popup i have to show 2 panels. But on alternate click of the button when the popup appears, nothing happens on clicking the panel. I had faced a similar type of issue where a grid was not loading properly on alternate click of the tab where it was present. I just emptied the grid using  `$("#GridId").empty` before every load and it worked. But i don't understand how to implement that concept in case of panel. I am using Kendo panels and grids. I am setting the panel items using `<ul> <li>` tags. It's working when i give `expandMode: "single"` for the panel bar but my requirement is to show all the panel dropdowns. Can someone help resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding this line `$("#Gridname").kendoPanelBar()`  in the `$(document).ready` function of the js file